# not working python scripts in Py4a in SL4a

Tags: android, python, sl4a

**What device(s) are you experiencing the problem on?**
Amoi N821

**What firmware version are you running on the device?**
Android 4.1.1

**What steps will reproduce the problem?**

1. Create the following Python script:

   ```
   import android
   droid = android.Android()
   droid.makeToast('Hello, Android!')
   print 'Hello world!'
   ```
2. Run script

**What is the expected output?**
must print 'Hello world!' & make popup 'Hello Android!'

**What do you see instead?** see this error:

dlopen libpython2.6.so

Traceback (most recent call list):

File "/storage/sdcard0/sl4a/scripts/hello_world.py", line 2, in

```
droid = droid.Android()
```

File "/storage/sdcard0/sl4a/scripts/android.py", line 34, in **Init**

```
self.conn = socket.create_connection(addr)
```

File "/home/manuel/AptanaStudio3Workspace/python-for-android/python-build/output/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 498, in create_connection

`socket.gaierror: [Errno 7] no address associated with hostname.`

.

.

**Please provide any additional information below.**
My friend has the same phone and the same problem.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried the built-in test.py script?

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem on my Lenovo P770. Later I confirmed that it was due to IPV6 binding to localhost by some software, or OEM ROM.
I was lucky enough to get help from Robbie Matthews on Google groups. He compiled a special SL4A package addressing this issue.

http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/Unofficial#Development_releases

If you work out, do not thank me. Thank him instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your script doesn't match your error message??

Your error includes the following line, which is incorrect.

```
droid = droid.Android()
```

It should be as you have written it in the example you gave.

```
droid = android.Android()
```